# How to add path in html5gallery href and src dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

While using this code 
the image and videos are not retrieved.

My code is

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function onSlideChange(data) {
                document.getElementById("images").src = "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/4gB7a.jpg";
        document.getElementById("vide").href = "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/4gB7a.jpg";
        try {
            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="html5gallery" data-width="480" data-height="270"
    data-onchange="onSlideChange" style="display: none;">
    <a href="" id="vide"><img src="" id="images"></a> <a
        href="http://localhost:8080/MyApp/2.jpg"><img
        src="http://localhost:8080/MyApp/2.jpg" alt="Island"></a>

</div>
```

Comment: `data-onchange` Did you mean `onchange` alone? `data-onchange` won't do anything by itself. (But inline handlers are bad practice - better to attach listeners properly with Javascript)

Comment: when i am using onchange alone its not working.

Comment: `div`s don't have `change` events except via delegation

Comment: Then how can we give without using click event "onclick"

Answer (score 0):

the id selector need to have a # sign. so you can try document.getElementById("#images") something like that